# What is the most efficient way to create a scheduled query in Redshift, which copies data from one table and enters it into an another?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm a novice to the Redshift, and was wondering what would be the most efficient way of updating one table (not merging by replacing) where I have userId,branchId and date with values from a Users table. The premise is to count the number of users in the branch (there is a branchId column in the Users table), and additionally set this task to reoccur every 24h. Is it possible in Redshift?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this but I'd lean toward Lambda function used in a Step function with a schedule.  If you need more cron-like behavior you can initiate the Lambda from a CloudWatch event on a cron schedule instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use Redshift Scheduled Queries directly in the Redshift Console

Redshift > Editor > Query Editor > Scheduled Queries